# $_POST method PHP issue

Tags: php

I'm currently working through a POST method problem in PHP. I'm given the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Within the PHP tags I am supposed to write PHP code that will check if a post request method has been used to access the page, and if so, print either "correct" or "incorrect" if the first name entered is equal to "John".

Here is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?
    if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
        echo 'Correct';
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
        echo 'Incorrect';
    }
    ?>
    <form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm just not quite sure how to incorporate the "John" condition and if I am on the right track. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a basic [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) like `==`:

```
<html>
<body>
<?
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && $_POST['firstname'] == 'John') {
    echo 'Correct';
}
else {
    echo 'Incorrect';
}
?>
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

A slightly better way to only do the check if the form is submitted. You can check to see if the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) has a key `REQUEST_METHOD` with a value of `POST`.

```
<html>
<body>
<?
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && $_POST['firstname'] == 'John') {
        echo 'Correct';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Incorrect';
    }
}
?>
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is *very basic* PHP. I suggest learning more about PHP and programming before going any further in your project.

Comment: Got it to work. Is it supposed to say incorrect above the form when I load the page? The instructions don't seem exactly clear.